# expect command not working

Tags: linux, expect

Hi all i am trying to automate using expect. I have a custom  utility  to  login to openstack  k8 distro

the custom command  is as below and it asks for an output

```
kubectl-openstack   login --server=10.1.1.1  --user=admin
```

I have 2 scripts

Script 1: login script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
kubectl-openstack   login --server=10.1.1.1  --user=admin
read $REPLY
```

Script 2: main script

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1

spawn ./login.sh
expect "Password: \r"
send -- "Answer!\r"
```

however nothing works... Any idea?

Comment: I'm lost. I have no idea what you're trying to automate with expect. You'll have to show us what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve with `read $REPLY`? Since that variable is unset at that point, bash sees the `read` command with no arguments, which takes a line of input and saves it in the REPLY variable. But then the bash script ends without using that value.

Comment: Hi gene... i was able to handle by  myself... thanks

Comment: No problem Art. For future readers you should either post an answer or delete the question, since it has no value as it currently stands.